# Electron app with webshot

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, electron

So, I am working on a small app built with Electron that crawl a website and take screenshot using webshot.

I am using the dialog module so the user can chose a folder to save the screenshots to.

the variable "filename" in the webshot callback is the path chosen by the user.

The expected behavior is :

- take a screenshot
- create a folder at the chosen path if it doesn't exist
- save screenshot

here is a simplified portion of the code:

```
var savePath = dialog.showSaveDialog(
    {
        title: 'save screenshots'
    },
    function(filename) {
                if(filename === undefined) {
                //if the user hit cancel return
                return;
                }

                //ScreenShots options
                var options = {
                    shotSize: {
                        height: 'all'
                    }
                };


               webshot(
               www.example.com/page.html,  
               filename+'/screen.png', 
               options, 
               function(err) {

               //some other logic that zip the folder
               zipFolder(screens_folder, folder_name );

              });

      });
```

This works as expected when I am launching the app from the command line doing a `electron .` how ever, when I package the app using electron builder, the webshot function fails with the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: spawn ENOTDIR    
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)    
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)    
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:392:9)    
    at Function.spawn (/Users/lorenzo/Desktop/web-dev/screenshots_app/dist/mac/screenShotApps.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:87:19)    
    at spawnPhantom (/Users/lorenzo/Desktop/web-dev/screenshots_app/dist/mac/screenShotApps.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/webshot/lib/webshot.js:201:32)    
    at spawn (/Users/lorenzo/Desktop/web-dev/screenshots_app/dist/mac/screenShotApps.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/webshot/lib/webshot.js:105:14)    
    at /Users/lorenzo/Desktop/web-dev/screenshots_app/dist/mac/screenShotApps.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/webshot/lib/webshot.js:117:16    
    at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (original-fs.js:257:19)
```

Edit: I am using node : 6.5.0, Chrome : 53.0.2785.113, Electron : 1.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution here after a lot of digging :

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/335

> The node spawn function in my app, which is a function
>   that doesn't work with asar archives. I had to read the code to figure
>   out how to stop electron-builder from archiving my app.
>
> All it takes is setting "asar": false in the build section of
>   package.json.